# React chart2js Line chart with multiple datasets overlapping

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mm34.png)

```
const data = {
    labels: Array(coordinates.length).fill("l"),
    datasets: buildDataset(),
    options: {
        animation: false,
        scales: {
            // ???????
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
               label: function(tooltipItem) {
                      return tooltipItem.yLabel;
               }
            }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            myScale: {
                position: 'left',
            }
        },
        elements: {
            point:{
                radius: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
return (
        <Chart>
            <Line
            data={data}
            width={50}
            height={20}
            options={data.options}>
            </Line>
        </Chart>
)
```

// ~~~~~

```
     let obj = {
        label: stops[0].miles == 0 ? index : index + 1,
        data: points,
        backgroundColor: colors[index],
        tension: 0.4,
        fill: true
    }
```

These charts are built from an array of `obj` objects. The `points` variable that data refers is an array of object like: `[{x: 0, y: 10257}, {x: 1, y: 10245}]`

How do I get my line chart to display these different datasets side by side? I assume it has something to do with the `scales` parameter but wasn't able to find anything that worked in the docs.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by side by side?

Comment: If you take a look at the photo, you'll see that the line graphs are all displayed starting at the origin. They are built from continuous data so I need them to not be overlapping

Comment: So you need to plot one after other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the object notation to work chart.js needs values to plot them against (not the index in the array) so you cant just provide an array containing only the value `l`.

You can either provide a labels array containing increasing numbers to which you match it or remove it and set your x scale to linear.

Labels example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 4
        }, {
          x: 1,
          y: 6
        }, {
          x: 2,
          y: 2
        }],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          x: 2,
          y: 2
        }, {
          x: 3,
          y: 3
        }],
        borderColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {}
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Linear example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 4
        }, {
          x: 1,
          y: 6
        }, {
          x: 2,
          y: 2
        }],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          x: 2,
          y: 2
        }, {
          x: 3,
          y: 3
        }],
        borderColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'linear'
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```